# How to reset tabulator row height after edit with a textarea editor?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Once I have edited a field with textarea as the editor the row height remains in an expanded state.
How can I automatically reset the row height to it's original height?

```
col_num: "4"
field: "tabulator_table_sql"
title: "Combo SQL"
visible: true
frozen: false
align: ""
editor: "textarea"
formatter: ""
validator: ""
width: "500"
decimals: "0"
widthGrow: ""
widthShrink: ""
headerFilter: "input"
headerFilterParams: ""
headerSort: false
sorter: ""
sorterParams: ""
headerSortTristate: false
headerVertical: false
combo_sql: ""
required: false
readonly: false
tablenamedisplay: "Tabulator Tables"
editorParams:
elementAttributes:
maxlength: "500"
__proto__: Object
verticalNavigation: "editor"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcsg57/tae6sjpv/51/

I am not using a formatter for the textarea editor. (i would rather have the row not be expanded) This results in the column being expanded on edit but when I leave the row I expected the row to return to the original height.
Is there a way to programmatically reset the row height?

Comment: please post a link to a JS Fiddle or Code Pen that shows your issue in action. your described behaviour does not match the expected table functionality

Comment: I have added a working fiddle. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The row height in your JS Fiddle does reset back to a single line once you have finished editing the cell.

If you want the cell to remain at the full height, you should use a ***textarea*** formatter in the column definition:

```
{field: "table_sql",title: "Table SQL",formatter: "textarea"}
```

On a side note, most of the options in your column don't need to be there, you only need to set a property if you want to change the default behaviour.